# Will A2P 10DLC registration required for US messaging, impact our active workflow process?

Tags: twilio, sms, registration, mms

I implemented a voice recording workflow in Twilio studio to allow employees to call in to record their name pronunciation. And the Twilio widget will send the recorded voice to my email address.  Everything works well.

Before we go live, I found a message in our Twilio phone number:

A2P 10DLC registration is required for US messaging. A registration process will be required for each US local number sending SMS/MMS messages to the US.

We haven't registered any A2P. Will that impact our application?  How hard/complicated is it to register A2P? And how long it will take?  If I start the registration process now, will it impact our workflow?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sending messages, you can ignore A2P 10DLC:

> The purpose of A2P 10DLC registration
> To ensure the responsible use of text messaging and maintain compliance with
> all regulations, U.S. wireless carriers now require all businesses **sending > messages** from 10-digit long code (10DLC) phone numbers to register those
> phone numbers and provide information about their texting use cases.

You will get warnings for sending messages if you have the Twilio default URL set for "a message comes in" and someone sends a text message to your Twilio phone number. If you have the default url provided by Twilio when someone sends you a message your phone number will automatically reply with a message. To prevent, remove the url for messaging from the phone number.

Restated, login to the Console, open the configuration for the number, make sure to remove "https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/sms/" from the phone number's Message Url.